# Branch Metrics url - deep link on desktop

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io

I have an web react app which has this kind of deep link:

http://test.com/app/#/project/123?apt=ITEM_DETAILS&apid=456

The main url of the app is http://test.com/app/#/ and i am using the path after that to route withing the app. The apt and apid params are deep link params which are used to open particular view/content in my react app.

I am trying to configure it with branch deep links.

I have the following branch link with the $fallback_url=:

https://xxx.test-app.link/Z9ejV6daZM

And i tried passing params to it like that:

https://xxx.test-app.link/Z9ejV6daZM?apt=ITEM_DETAILS&apid=456

Also i tried passing params into data, but still no success.

It redirects to to
http://test.com/app/?_branch_match_id=524923164188531725#/

Can you let me know how can i create dynamically branch link so that it can handle the # + adding http GET params like mines. This is for desktop.

For mobile i think that adding the $deeplink_path or params in data will work.

Comment: you can refer to the guide [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#create-deep-link) to create a custom line in your react app.

Comment: while creating the link in your app, you can add the custom parameters as required. These parameters can be read in your app by using the Branch SDK in your app, as shown in the guide [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/react-native/#read-deep-link). You can also read these parameters on your website, by using the web SDK as shown [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#read-deep-link)

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh I am generating the links on the backend and send them in emails. I can't generate the links on the app frontend.